# How and where to pass the application data language if the application is multilingual?

Tags: karate

In our web-based application, `URL` includes data language but in order to create data in application, user needs to pass the language in scenario URL in each scenario?

Can we include the language in the background so that user don't need to pass the language in each scenario? Kindly suggest.

Eg. https://localhost:8092/xyz?lang=en_US

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `* param lang = "en_US"` to the background?

Comment: Thank you for response.
What if we want to use this lang at the end of API URL (as a part of url)  and that too with in each scenario?

Comment: I think that to do that, you would need to define a String variable in the karate-config.js file, and add that at the end of each URL you call.